# Como colocar imagens na tag select em asp-net core?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor, asp-net-core

```
<select>
  <option background="https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/gb.svg">gb</option>
  <option background="https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/pt.svg">pt</option>
</select>

<!-------Versão em .net core ------>
<form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <select name="culture" onchange="this.form.submit();" asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems"></select>
</form>
```

No fundo eu queria que aparecesse as imagens nesse select